# Wrong DateFormat with Jquery Datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker, asp.net-mvc-5, date-format, html.textboxfor

I want to exclude the `time` part in the DateTime Textbox, but I can't make it work the way I want.

This is how I set up the field :

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DateFrom, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @class = "datefrom" })
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DateTo, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @class = "dateto" })
```

Jquery script:

```
    $(function () {
        $(".datefrom").datepicker({
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            changeMonth: true,  
            numberOfMonths: 1,
            dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
            onClose: function (selectedDate) {
                $("#to").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
            }
        });
        $(".dateto").datepicker({
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            changeMonth: true,
            numberOfMonths: 1,
            dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
            onClose: function (selectedDate) {
                $("#from").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
            }
        });
    });
```

Now I have these problems :

- the `time` always appear in the field :

[image]

- the `date format` is wrong : my format is dd/MM/yyyy, the date is `November 8th 2014` but now the datepicker "thinks" it is `August 10th 2014`. So when I choose an arbitrary date from the datepicker by the format `dd/MM/yyyy` , asp.net will treate it with the format `MM/dd/yyyy`

What I have tried :

- I tried to use `DataAnnotations` : `[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]` : not worked
- I tried to remove the Jquery script, not worked

P/s : althought the datetime textbox contains `time` part at the first load, after choosing a date from the datepicker, the `time` part is gone, but the date is in the wrong format as I mentioned above :

[image]

Comment: Note `[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode=true)]` is only applicable if you use `@EditorFor()` so its not necessary in you case. Your code for `@Html.TextBoxFor()` looks fine and works for me so something else is causing the problem.

Comment: @StephenMuecke : now it's displaying correctly, but when I hit the submit button, the value sent to the controller is still in `MM/dd/yyyy` format, headace!

Comment: Whats the culture on the server? It also needs to match that format for the date to bind correctly. And setting `@Value = ...` is not necessary - if you need to do this then there is some other issue.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I'm running on my own laptop, and the dateformat of my laptop is MM/dd/yyyy, is this the cause of the problem?

Comment: Change the format on your lap top to `dd/MM/yyyy` to check. I suspect it will now work correctly. You probably need to create a custom model binder to ensure the posted values are parsed to the correct date if you have different client and server side formats.

Comment: @StephenMuecke after changing the date format on my machine, it's working fine. I also take a look at examples online for custom model binding and found it hard to understand. Could you provide a simple sample please?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Oh nevermind, I got it :)thanks anyway !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you date is not being correctly bound is that your datepicker is using `dd/MM/yyy` format, but you server is using `MM/dd/yyyy` format. To make this work, you can create a custom model binder to handle `DateTime` values and parse them to the format you want.

```
public class CustomDateTimeBinder : IModelBinder
{
  public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
  {
    var value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
    CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("en-GB"); // dd/MM/yyyy
    var date = value.ConvertTo(typeof(DateTime), culture);
    return date;
  }
}
```

and register it in `Global.asax` (this means it will apply to all `DateTime` values

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(DateTime), new YourAssembly.CustomDateTimeBinder());
```