# Change date format in whole application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, globalization

I am working on asp.net mvc2 application. Problem is that when i am displaying date in format `MM/dd/yyyy` application work, but i must display the date in format `dd/MM/yyyy` to user. I set date in this format, but then i have problem with web service because it expect date format in `MM/dd/yyyy`, and i always get an error.

First i thought to write simple method that would convert date from one format to another ,and display in `dd/MM/yyyy` . But i have to match methods that use date, and i will have to make changes at many places.

I tried to use globalization in web config file like

```
​    <system.web>
​​        <globalization 
             requestEncoding="utf-8"
             responseEncoding="utf-8"
             culture="en-GB"
             uiCulture="en-GB" 
        />
    </system.web>
```

But that did not work for me. Is there some way to change date format when i display to the user, and then web service can accept it?

Thanks

Comment: Does this help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Its MM (month) not mm (minutes). Setting the culture on the server should be fine, or you can create a custom model binder [Refer example here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26813345/wrong-dateformat-with-jquery-datepicker/26813682#26813682)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion `en-GB` is the correct setting for `culture` and `uiCulture` since this is the culture which has the date format you want to show to the user: `dd/MM/yyyy`

In those places where you are calling an API which requires the `MM/dd/yyyy` you should specify the format explicitly as `MM/dd/yyyy` like this:

```
myDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I put the CultureInfo.InvariantCulture there so that there is no chance that the serialization will be affected by future changes in the `culture` and `uiCulture` settings for the application.